# Merge MultiLine records using pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataset like which as a multiline and multi delitmer. I am using spark 2.3 to read the same.

i wanted to convert into a single line file with a different delimeter

```
1223232|*|1212|*|0|*|0|*||*|ABDP|*|1234|*|asda|##|
12223212|*|1212|*|0|*|0|*||*|ABD
[c0re] score 
12-- 12--P|*|1234|*|asda|##|
1223232|*|1212|*|0|*|0|*||*|ABDP|*|1234|*|asda|##|
2334343|*|1212|*|0|*|0|*||*|ABD
[c0re] score 
12-- 12--P|*|1223|*|asda|##|
1223232|*|1212|*|0|*|0|*||*|ABDP|*|1234|*|asda|##|
```

Expected output

```
1223232~1212~0~0~~ABDP~1234~asda
12223212~1212~0~0~~ABD[c0re] score 12-- 12--P~1234~asda
1223232~1212~0~0~~ABDP~1234~asda
2334343~1212~0~0~~ABD[c0re] score 12-- 12--P~1223~asda
1223232~1212~0~0~~ABDP~1234~asda
```

This file was initially converted using a UNIX sed commands. However the size of the file grew and is 50GB and the servers is being hung.

```
while read myline
do
sed -i 's/\r//g' $myline
sed -i ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g' $myline # removes new line
sed -i 's+|\#\#|+\n+g' $myline #replaces all |##| as new line
sed -i 's/~/-/g' $myline 
sed -i 's/\\/  /g' $myline
sed -i 's+|\*|+~+g' $myline # converts all |*| as ~
sed -i 's+|\#\#|++g' $myline
done < filename
```

This has to be rewritten into spark with multichracters delimters and newline in data its notworking out.

I have the spark code written as but unsure how to treat the |#| as newline or eod instead of newline and reaplce newline with space may be

```
df = sc.textFile(source_filename).map(lambda x: x.split("|*|")).toDF(header_column)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm managing to execute your data partitioned by file, but it will requires a big cluster as well, since you mentioned that has files over 30Gb.

```py
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as f


df = spark.read.csv('your_path', schema='value string')
df = df.withColumn('filename', f.input_file_name())
df = df.repartition('filename')

df = df.withColumn('index', f.monotonically_increasing_id())

w = Window.partitionBy('filename').orderBy('index')
df = df.withColumn('group', f.sum(f.lag('value', default=False).over(w).endswith(f.lit('|##|')).cast('int')).over(w))

df = df.withColumn('value', f.regexp_replace('value', '\|\*\|', '~'))
df = df.withColumn('value', f.regexp_replace('value', '\|##\|', ''))

df = df.groupBy('group').agg(f.concat_ws('', f.collect_list('value')).alias('value'))
(df
 .select('value')
 .sort('group')
 .show(truncate=False))
```

Output

```
+-------------------------------------------------------+
|value                                                  |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
|1223232~1212~0~0~~ABDP~1234~asda                       |
|12223212~1212~0~0~~ABD[c0re] score 12-- 12--P~1234~asda|
|1223232~1212~0~0~~ABDP~1234~asda                       |
|2334343~1212~0~0~~ABD[c0re] score 12-- 12--P~1223~asda |
|1223232~1212~0~0~~ABDP~1234~asda                       |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

The delimiter in Spark's `split` is actually a regular expression, so you will need to escape pipe `|` and asterisk `*` symbols.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

(spark
    .read.text('a.txt')
    .withColumn('tmp', F.explode(F.split(F.col('value'), '\|##\|')))
    .withColumn('tmp', F.regexp_replace(F.col('tmp'), '\|\*\|', '~'))
    .select('tmp')
    .show(10, False)
)

# EDIT: since the data is **not** single line, hence the updated code below.
# I created "fake ID" to group records together based on its indexes
(spark
    .read.text('a.txt')
    .withColumn('id', F.monotonically_increasing_id())
    .withColumn('grp', (F.col('id') / 4).cast('int'))
    .groupBy('grp')
    .agg(F.collect_list('value').alias('value'))
    .withColumn('value', F.concat_ws('', 'value'))
    .withColumn('value', F.explode(F.split(F.col('value'), '\|##\|')))
    .withColumn('value', F.regexp_replace(F.col('value'), '\|\*\|', '~'))
    .where(F.col('value') != '')
    .drop('grp')
    .show(10, False)
)

# +-------------------------------------------------------+
# |tmp                                                    |
# +-------------------------------------------------------+
# |1223232~1212~0~0~~ABDP~1234~asda                       |
# |12223212~1212~0~0~~ABD[c0re] score 12-- 12--P~1234~asda|
# |1223232~1212~0~0~~ABDP~1234~asda                       |
# |2334343~1212~0~0~~ABD[c0re] score 12-- 12--P~1223~asda |
# |1223232~1212~0~0~~ABDP~1234~asda                       |
# |                                                       |
# +-------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: It didn't work for me . The result stays the same when read as text i think newline is taken to read and rows are treated separate

Comment: Note that in your sample above, you added the newline after each `|##|`. My `a.txt` is a single line like this `1223232|*|1212|*|0|*|0|*||*|ABDP|*|1234|*|asda|##|12223212|*|1212|*|0|*|0|*||*|ABD[c0re] score 12-- 12--P|*|1234|*|asda|##|1223232|*|1212|*|0|*|0|*||*|ABDP|*|1234|*|asda|##|2334343|*|1212|*|0|*|0|*||*|ABD[c0re] score 12-- 12--P|*|1223|*|asda|##|1223232|*|1212|*|0|*|0|*||*|ABDP|*|1234|*|asda|##|`

Comment: Yes there is newline in data and end of line as well

Comment: Hm I'm not following, so what are you stuck now? does this answer your question?

Comment: My file had multi character delimiter and new line breaks. I need solution for having multi line

Comment: My file had multi character delimiter and new line breaks. I need solution for having multi line. Your solution works if its single line file without newline. I have a file which is 60GB and cannot be read a wholeFile text as well. I even tried with executor memory upto 40Gb( just to see if it works