# Filter Header 2 rows and Trailer 1 row in 1000 of huge files pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have list multiple 1000's of huge files in a folder ..

Each file is having 2 header rows and trailer row

```
file1
H|*|F|*|TYPE|*|EXTRACT|*|Stage_|*|2021.04.18 07:35:26|##|
H|*|TYP_ID|*|TYP_DESC|*|UPD_USR|*|UPD_TSTMP|##|
E|*||*|CONNECTOR|*|2012.06.01 09:03:11|##|
H|*|Tracking|*|asdasasd|*|2011.03.04 11:50:51|##|
S|*|Tracking|*|asdasdas|*|2011.03.04 11:51:06|##|
T|*|3|*|2021.04.18 07:35:43|##|
file 2
H|*|F|*|PA__STAT|*|EXTRACT|*|Folder|*|2021.04.18 07:35:26|##|
H|*|STAT_ID|*|STAT_DESC|*|UPD_USR|*|UPD_TSTMP|##|
A|*|Active / Actif|*|1604872|*|2018.06.25 15:12:35|##|
D|*||*|CONNECTOR|*|2012.04.06 10:49:09|##|
I|*|Intermittent Leave|*|asdasda|*|2021.04.09 13:14:00|##|
L|*|On Leave|*|asdasasd|*|2011.03.04 11:49:40|##|
P|*|Paid Leave|*|asdasd|*|2011.03.04 11:49:56|##|
T|*|Terminated / TerminÃ©|*|1604872|*|2018.06.25 15:13:06|##|
U|*||*|CONNECTOR|*|2012.06.16 09:04:14|##|
T|*|7|*|2021.04.18 07:35:55|##|

file3

H|*|K|*|PA_CPN|*|EXTRACT|*|SuccessFactors|*|2021.04.22 23:09:26|##|
H|*|COL_NUM|*|CPNT_TYP_ID|*|CPNT_ID|*|REV_DTE|##|
40|*|OLL|*|asdasdas|*|2019.01.21 14:07:00|##|
40|*|OLL|*|asdasda|*|2019.01.21 14:18:00|##|
40|*|OLL|*|asdasdas|*|2019.01.21 14:20:00|##|
T|*|3|*|2021.04.22 23:27:17|##|
```

I am applying a filter on lines starting with H|*| and T|*|  but it is rejecting the data for few rows.

```
df_cleanse=spark.sql("select replace(replace(replace(value,'~','-'),'|*|','~'),'|##|','') as value from linenumber3 where value not like 'T|*|%' and value not like 'H|*|%'")
```

I know we can use zipwithindex , but i have to read file by file and and they apply zip index and then filter on the rows .

```
for each file:
    df = spark.read.text('file1')
    #Adding index column each row get its row numbers , Spark distibutes the data and to maintain the order of data we need to perfrom this action
    df_1 = df.rdd.map(lambda r: r).zipWithIndex().toDF(['value', 'index'])
    df_1.createOrReplaceTempView("linenumber")
    spark.sql("select * from linenumber where index >1 and value.value not like 'T|*|%'")
```

Please let know the optimal solution for the same. I do not want to run a extensive program all i need is to juts remove 3 lines . Even a regex to remove the rows is fine we need to process TB's of files in this format
Unix Commands and Sed operators are ruled out due to the file sizes

Comment: Do you want only remove the lines that starts with H|*| or T|*|?

Comment: I need to remove the first 2 lines and last line in each file. Starts with H|_| and T|_| logic removing data as well

Comment: Can you update your question showing the desired output for file_2 as example? I want to know if I really understood

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile I wait your answer, try this to remove the first two lines and the last:

```py
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as f


df = spark.read.csv('your_path', schema='value string')

df = df.withColumn('filename', f.input_file_name())
df = df.repartition('filename')
df = df.withColumn('index', f.monotonically_increasing_id())

w = Window.partitionBy('filename')
df = (df
      .withColumn('remove', (f.col('index') == f.max('index').over(w)) | (f.col('index') < f.min('index').over(w) + f.lit(2)))
      .where(~f.col('remove'))
      .select('value'))

df.show(truncate=False)
```

Output

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|value                                                        |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|E|*||*|CONNECTOR|*|2012.06.01 09:03:11|##|                   |
|H|*|Tracking|*|asdasasd|*|2011.03.04 11:50:51|##|            |
|S|*|Tracking|*|asdasdas|*|2011.03.04 11:51:06|##|            |
|A|*|Active / Actif|*|1604872|*|2018.06.25 15:12:35|##|       |
|D|*||*|CONNECTOR|*|2012.04.06 10:49:09|##|                   |
|I|*|Intermittent Leave|*|asdasda|*|2021.04.09 13:14:00|##|   |
|L|*|On Leave|*|asdasasd|*|2011.03.04 11:49:40|##|            |
|P|*|Paid Leave|*|asdasd|*|2011.03.04 11:49:56|##|            |
|T|*|Terminated / TerminÃ©|*|1604872|*|2018.06.25 15:13:06|##||
|U|*||*|CONNECTOR|*|2012.06.16 09:04:14|##|                   |
|40|*|OLL|*|asdasdas|*|2019.01.21 14:07:00|##|                |
|40|*|OLL|*|asdasda|*|2019.01.21 14:18:00|##|                 |
|40|*|OLL|*|asdasdas|*|2019.01.21 14:20:00|##|                |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks Kafels let me trying for the huge files if it succeeds.

Comment: As expected its failing for files which are >30Gb files...

Comment: Increased the memory and then it worked.. Can you take a look at this as well.. handling line (newline on data )breaks on this file as well.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67579000/merge-multiline-records-using-pyspark

Comment: Logic also breaks for bigger files.. only smaller files it works